# How to cancel "git stash pop" when I staged my diffs but not commit them?

Tags: git

Example.
I wrote some code, staged it I wanted to do commit but I did "git stash pop" accidentally. In stash, files staged also. Is there a way to cancel the code that I got after "pop" and just leave that code I wrote and staged before?

Comment: If your code is already staged you can just commit and then afterwards reset to HEAD or save the stash again.

Comment: My stashed files have staged too. If I do commit stashed files with my new diffs will be in commit too

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

The short answer is that you may have to do a lot of work, or just a little work.  There's no *automated* way to get back what you had.

#### Long

> Example. I wrote some code, staged it I wanted to do commit ...

So far, everything is OK.  Before I get to the next steps, though, I want to describe exactly what this all means.

The main bulk of a Git repository consists of two databases.  One holds *all the commits* and other internal Git objects, and the other holds names: branch names, tag names, and other such names.  The names are mostly used to *find the commits*.  Each commit is numbered, with a unique (and big and ugly) hash ID that appears random, so we need some mechanism to find particularly interesting commits, such as the most recent commit for some branch.  Commits themselves store the commit numbers of other commits, so once we find some particularly interesting commit—such as the latest `master` or `develop` commit, for instance—we can use that commit to find other interesting commits; but we need the hash ID of that one particular commit, to get started.

With all that in mind, remember also that every commit is *completely, totally, 100% read-only*.  Nothing about any commit can ever *change*, once you make the commit.  And, each commit stores a *full archive of every file*.  To make this archive not use up all your disk space quickly, the stored files inside commits are in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form.

What all this means is that you cannot actually *use* any commit.  Or rather, you can't use it until you first have Git *un-archive* it, to turn its saved archive back into ordinary files.  This is what `git checkout` or the new (since Git 2.23) `git switch` is for: you tell Git *get me the latest `master` commit* or *get me the latest `develop` commit*.  Git uses the names database to find the big ugly hash ID of that particular commit, then uses the *archive inside that commit* to populate a working tree full of usable files.

Git calls this area, with the usable files that you can work on and with, your *working tree*.  You do your work here, in your working tree.

**The working tree files are not the ones that are inside the Git repository.**  They are *copies*, made *from* those files; but the files inside the Git repository are in a different, Git-only format.  **When you make a new commit, Git will have to re-Git-ize all the files, and this process would be very slow, so Git doesn't just do it over again.**  Instead, Git *keeps all of the Git-ized files from the last commit*.  These are in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  **Initially, the cached copies here exactly match the commit you checked out.**

As you work on the working tree, the *cached index copies* get out of sync with the *working tree* copies.  They still match the old committed copies, because they're not yet changed.

When you run `git add`, what Git does *replace the cached index copies*.  Git reads your working tree copy of the file, and compresses and de-duplicates it to turn it into the Git-only format, and drops that into the cache.  This replaces the old copy that *was* in the index / staging-area.  The new one is *ready to be committed*.  (So was the old one: it's just that it matched the copy from the commit you checked out!)

Once the *index* copy of some file is *different from the committed copy*, Git starts calling that file `staged for commit`.  In fact, though, Git's index / staging-area has *every* file in it.  It's just that some of them still match the existing committed files: they're pre-de-duplicated duplicates.  The other files, that you updated with `git add`, are also pre-de-duplicated: if they match any committed file anywhere in the repository, committing now will re-use the old file.  If they're all-new, committing now will add one all-new file (technically, one all-new *blob object*) to the repository's object database.

So: having staged some files really means *making new, pre-de-duplicated copies and replacing the old pre-de-duplicated index copies with the new ones*.

> ... but I did "git stash pop" accidentally.

Now we get into the tricky bits.  The `git stash` command itself, when it makes a stash, really just *makes some commits*.  It makes two commits, or sometimes three.  What's special about these commits are that they are not on *any* branch.  But otherwise, they're just commits: running `git stash save` makes a couple of new commits.  Like any commit, these two commits contain full snapshots of every file.  The tricky part is what's *in* these two commits, and how they get used *later*, with `git stash pop` or `git stash apply`.

> In stash, files staged also.

This is, by definition, wrong: to say that some file is *staged* means *the index copy of the file differs from the current-commit copy*.  But all files in the two stash commits are in *commits*.  So nothing *in the stash itself* is *staged*.  The index itself is independent of the two stash commits.

But: when you run `git stash pop`, you must *choose what to do with each of the two stash commits*.  You can choose to *ignore the first of the commits entirely*, and that's the default.  Only if you run `git stash pop --index` does Git use *both* commits.

It's now time to look at the two commits in some stash, and how they get applied during `git stash apply` or `git stash pop`:

- The *first* of the two commits matches what you would have gotten, had you run `git commit`: it has all the files that were in Git's index at the time you ran `git stash`.  If you do run `git stash pop --index`, Git *attempts to apply this commit to the current index contents*, in a fairly complicated manner.  This either succeeds without conflicts, or nothing at all happens and Git says that the stash cannot be applied (and the entire `git stash pop --index` is aborted).

  (If using `--index` and there is a success here, Git puts the result away in a temporary area at this point, because the next step needs to use the index, and Git now resets the index as if with `git reset --mixed`.)
- The *second* of the two commits matches what you would have gotten, had you run `git add -u` and then `git commit`: it has in it all the files that were in your working tree that had corresponding files in Git's index.  Assuming you omitted `--index`, or the index commit was successfully applied, Git now goes on to run `git merge-recursive`.  This attempts to merge the *current contents of your working tree* with what's in the second commit, using the second commit's parent commit as the merge base.

  Note that this step, unlike regular `git merge`, does not require that your working tree be "clean".  If this merge *fails*, Git turns the `git stash pop` into a `git stash apply` (i.e., does not *drop* the stash), and stops with whatever mess is left in both your working tree and Git's index.  **This may not be recoverable in any automatic fashion.**

Anyway, once you've followed this through to this point, it's time to mention the possibility of a *third* commit in a stash.  **At the time you make a stash** you can use the `-u` or `-a` options to put *untracked* files into a third commit.  If you choose this option, `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` will attempt to restore this *third* commit early on.  If that fails, `git stash` won't run `git merge-recursive` on your working tree at all and in effect nothing at all happens.  There is no option to skip this third commit: it is used if it exists, and not used if it does not.  `git stash list` probably should annotate the list with something about whether the third commit exists, and `git stash show` should mention something here, but they don't.  So you must remember whether you made any three-commit stashes.

Now, let's assume normal two-commit stashes *and* that you *did not* run `git stash pop --index` here:

> Is there a way to cancel the code that I got after "pop" and just leave that code I wrote and staged before?

If the `pop` operation thinks it finished successfully, it ran `git stash drop` as its last step.  This *discarded the stash commits*, and since they were never on any branch at all, they may be garbage-collected and thrown out forever at any point after this.  **I recommend avoiding `git stash pop`.**  Use `git stash apply` instead, which *does not* run `git stash drop`.  Then, once you're sure the stash is correctly applied and you don't want it, run `git stash drop` separately.

If the `pop` operation thinks something went wrong—because you got merge conflicts—then you still have the *stash itself*.  Unfortunately, you have lost the carefully staged arrangement of files that you had earlier, because the `git merge-recursive` step that used the working tree commit in the stash has modified Git's index.  Merging takes place *in* the index, using the working tree as extra scratch space when there are conflicts.

Had you run `git stash` *before* this `git stash pop`, you would have made a commit from what was in Git's index, and that commit would contain what you wanted.  Of course you would then have had to address the *other* stash some other way, and because `git stash push` / `git stash save` ends with a `git reset --hard` or equivalent, you would also have needed to run `git stash apply --index` first.  But you didn't do these, so you have whatever Git left you, after the `git merge-recursive` step.

My own recommendation is to *avoid* `git stash` as much as possible.  Remember that it works by making commits.  These commits are hard to see (because they're on *no* branch) and hard to use (because only the `git stash` command itself can use them correctly), and they don't do anything you could not do with normal everyday commits.  The everyday commits are easy to see and easy to use.  Stash does have one advantage, which is that because the commits it makes are on *no* branch, it's easy to make them on one branch and apply them on another without having to think about it, but that one advantage is pretty small—and the *not having to think* part leads to *not thinking*, which leads to misery when the stash *doesn't* apply cleanly.

Comment: It's not easy to understand everything you wrote...
So to prevent this case I need to git stash pop --index?

Comment: If you want the index arrangement back, yes, you need `git stash apply --index`. Note that, as I said above, I recommend *avoiding* `git stash pop`. Use `apply`, and then *after* you are sure you are *completely done* with the applied stash, use `git stash drop` to drop it. (Of course I also recommend avoiding `git stash` entirely, too. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to undo what you did.

From the `git stash` manpage:

> `push [-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-q|--quiet] [-m|--message <message>] [--pathspec-from-file=<file> [--pathspec-file-nul]] [--] [<pathspec>...]`
>
> Save your local modifications to a new stash entry and roll them back to HEAD (in the working tree and in the index). The `<message>` part is optional and gives the description along with the stashed state.
>
> For quickly making a snapshot, you can omit "push". In this mode, non-option arguments are not allowed to prevent a misspelled subcommand from making an unwanted stash entry. The two exceptions to this are stash -p
> which acts as alias for stash push -p and pathspec elements, which are allowed after a double hyphen -- for disambiguation.

You just need to `git stash push -- <files>` in order to push them to a new stash. Since you are not saying that you are getting any conflicts, I assume that you just need to remember what needs to be in the stash and what needs to be left in the staging area.

If you are unsure what to save and what to stash, then you can check in your console the output of `git stash pop`, since it will tell you the sha1 of the stash you poped:

```
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (fcb1753544d849af2548bafa48c4d74debbda518)
```

---

**Edit/Note:** If you *did get conflicts*, then git will complain during the `stash pop` phase and you will have to solve said conflicts. Git will save the stash however :) so you don't need to stress about loosing your stash in that scenario.

Comment: If I do like this "git stash push -- <files>" then all my diffs new and from pop will be in stash

Comment: You just specify the files that were in your stash, don't specify the files that you want to commit.

Comment: I have a lot of files which had in my stage. How to understand which one I have to git stash push -- <files>?

Comment: @HackerMF one option is to do something like `git diff <stash-sha1> HEAD`. If you don't know your stash sha1, there is a chance it's still around and you can try to find it with `git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}'`.